# Display Images one by one with next and previous functionality

Tags: php, mysql

I have stored images in a separate folder (images) and created a database that stores letterNumber and with each letterNumber several images are associated.

The table (annimages) is as follows.

```
letterNo, imageNo,    path,    height, width
   1         1      images/1a    700    630
   1         2      images/1b    710    628
   1         3      images/1c    705    630   `
```

Likewise I have 20 letters.

Now in PHP, I am able to retrive images on the web page with the following code.

```
$query="SELECT letterNo, width, height, path from annimages where letterNo=".$letterNumber;
$rs=mysql_query($query,$connection);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<img src="' .$row['path'].'.jpg"' .' width="'.$row['width'].'" height="'.$row['height'].'" alt=Letter "'.$letterNumber.'" />'. '<br/>';
}
```

The problem is: when I click from navigation bar letter number = 1, it will display all images associated with letter number 1. All in one click but I want to show images one by one with next and previous hyperlink.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Are you aware of mysql LIMIT? typically used in combination with ORDER BY to implement pagination: "ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 1" - Just google search "mysql limit". It should clarify anything you need

Comment: Thanks @Madara Uchiha and Kai Qing. I have included LIMIT and Order by clause but have no further idea for next and prev. I've commented it's code in the following post so you can comment on it. Thanks for suggesting PDO tutorial Also I am novice for PHP. Can you suggest me any book or good tutorial with examples for PHP and MySQL please.

Answer (score 0):

You are only using 1 filtering field you need to use both (letteNo and imageNo)

```
$query="SELECT letterNo, width, height, path from annimages where letterNo=".$letterNumber." AND imageNo=".$imageNo." LIMIT 1";
$rs=mysql_query($query,$connection);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)
echo '<br/>';
echo '<img src="'.$row['path'].'.jpg"'.'width="'.$row['width'].'"height="'.$row['height'].'" alt=Letter "'.$letterNumber.'" />'.'<br/>';
```

mysql LIMIT keyword limits how many rows are returned, though you dont need it if each combination of letterNo and imageNo relate to a single row. Though it is good to have a limit incase you dont catch all mysql injection attacks.

and each previous next link will need to pass the next letterNo and imageNo

And of course do as Madara Uchiha suggests in his comment and use mysqli api as the mysql api is depreciated

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. It seems that I know outdated MySQL.  At the moment I'm bit scared looking to PDO and mysqli stuff but I'll again look into the suggested links. As Patrick Evans, you've suggested to use letterNO and imageNo together. `select letterNo, imageNo, width, height, path from annimages LIMIT 1 where letterNo=1 orderby letterNo, imageNo ASC;` Should I write this way? Then how the other rows will follow for next and prev images. I am sorry but I don't have that much knowledge. your help is appreciable. Thanks. Toie.

Comment: The way you are stating your problem you are saying you want to show one image then have the user click a link (previous or next) and the next page displays the previous/next image so you only want the query to return 1 image. If however you mean you want to hide all the other images and dynamically show the previous/next image then i will have to update the answer, but you should update your question to reflect that you want it done dynamically done on the same page so others know what you mean. If thats what you mean let me know and i will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification Patrick Evans. I am updating my question here. I have 20 letters. Each letter has some images. Lets say LetterNo 1 is consists of 5 images, Letter2 is of 3 images.    Here I am able to retrieve images related to letterNo and all images are currently displayed in sequence but the problem is all images are shown in one page. Instead I want to show images one by one but on the same PHP page.    Does it require to write the above code again?      Your help is really appreciable.     Thanks a lot. Toie