# Dynamically show the previous/next image using click but on the same page (DIV tag) -

Tags: php, mysql

I am updating [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861390/display-images-one-by-one-with-next-and-previous-functionality) here. I have stored images in a separate folder called annimages. I have created a database which stores path of the images.

The database is as follows.

`letterNo  imageNo height width path

    1          1          600      700     annDB/1.jpg

    1           2          630      710     annDB/2.jpg

    1           3          620      720     annDB/3.jpg

    2           1          650      700     annDB/4.jpg

    2           2          700      800     annDB/5.jpg`

Likewise, I have 20 letters but all letters contains different number of images.

Now from PHP,

```
$query="SELECT letterNo, width, height, path from annimages where letterNo=".$letterNumber;    
$rs=mysql_query($query,$connection);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
echo '<img src="' .$row['path'].'.jpg"' .' width="'.$row['width'].'" height="'.$row['height'].'" alt=Letter "'.$letterNumber.'" />';
}
```

Using this code I am able to retrieve all images related to LetterNo and displayed on the webpage.

What I want, as images are retrieved from the database and stored in PHP page. Now from webpage using Previous and Next click I want move through images but in the same page (DIV tag). I don't want to leave that page.

Comment: Using javascript/jquery library, you can do xmlhttprequest's to a separate php file that can return the data you want, and fill it into your DIV.

Comment: If you want us to give you an idea how it could be implemented, you may take @RobW's comment as a guide

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use that is by AJAX , make a simple AJAX call , you can use Jquery framework which is very useful and easy, Make a javaScript function with XMLHttpRequest , and give the different parameter to your php file , ex if your file is located at www.somewhere.com/abc.php?image=1 then pass this parameter to your AJAX function use the parameter in your php file , increment the URL every time it is clicked or decrease it.